# Where are receipts for App Store purchases on OS X

Tags: mac-appstore

I recently upgraded to Lion, which has been good so far. My employer likes receipts for the things I purchase though. Is there some place where you can see what you bought through the OS X App Store and how much you paid for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a receipt by Email a couple of hours up to days after you bought something on the App Store. There is no way to tell how long it will take though.

Comment: You are right, it just took them 24 hours or so...